# Is sending password in email safe

Tags: passwords, password-protection, change-password, forgot-password

In our company was decided to send password in email, on registration and on forgot password. I am asking if there could be some security issues with this?

Comment: are you using ajax or not?

Comment: Your question only asks if it is safe or not. I have given the answer specific to your question. If you need to know the other options you can use, please ask another question.

Comment: @Araz we send email from server side

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/is-sending-password-to-user-email-secure for an alternative take on this

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is NO. It is not safe.

Furthermore, the server should NOT store the passwords in the DB in plain-text, and the server should not keep then encoded/encrypted in a way that the password can be decoded/decrypted.

The server should handle differently "forgot password" flow. You can read more [here](https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows/tree/master/authentication-flows#forgot-password-flow) (Java project that implements all flows...):

https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows/tree/master/authentication-flows#forgot-password-flow

Comment: Oh but Airbnb do it (no expiry and not forced to change on first login) so it must be fine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Storing passwords in a human readable format anywhere cannot be considered as safe. But most of the service providers send passwords via email so it is the choice the system administrator needs to make.

Comment: i agree with that. it answers the question perfectly. In one word: NO.